# Google Cloud SQL Instance failed with unknown error and cannot start, stop, edit or restore

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform

We've been using Google Cloud SQL Server for the last few months no problem.

This morning, we had a standard system maintenance that failed and took down our whole production environment. We cannot get it to come back online through any avenue.

When we click on stop or restart, it gives the error "The attempted action failed, please try again. Request ID: 1467983782194077276"

When we try to restore, it says you can't restore with replicas but we are on SQL Server so we couldn't actually set up a replica. I looked through the documentation and there is literally no way for SQL Server to create or manage replicas

When we try to export, import, or edit, the instance overview page just reloads with nothing different.

The logs are useless (= unknown error) and I have tried everything I could find in documentation. We are on free cloud support, and it takes 5 days to activate, so I cannot even ask someone at Google.

Has anyone seen this before? What can I do to get our production back online?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide us with more information on the standard system maintenance that took place before the issues occurred? Also any screenshots of the error messages you got will give us a better understanding as well.

In addition, when you had tried to restore the SQL instance, what methods did you follow to do so? This will help us understand what produces were already followed to resolve the issue.

Furthermore, can you please provide us with the current state of this SQL instance? Is it producing any errors? Is it operating? etc.

Comment: Thanks for asking for more clarity.

After submitting to Google's bug tracker, their engineers identified it was something on their end that we could not have done and could not have fixed. It took them ~7 hours to fully resolve, and then we were back online.

No further action at this point as I'm not aware of anything we could have done differently on our end to mitigate.

FYI, this boiled down to a broken maintenance update script that they pushed out in the morning.